# In Quill.js, I want Enter to submit messages and Shift + Enter to create a new line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, keyboard-events, quill

I have a **React app** with **Quill version 1.3.7**.

**For context/refresher:** The default behaviour of Enter in a Quill text editor is to create a new line. I want to change that.

I wrote the below function so that when user presses enter, it'll submit the message. But turns out, it both sends the message *and* creates a new line. I don't want it to create a newline (it is essential that I prevent creating newline, as opposed to letting it create a new line and then removing it).

```
const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior of adding a new line
      const strippedHTML = newMessage.replace(/(<p><br><\/p>)+/gi, '').trim();
      if (strippedHTML || /^\s*$/.test(strippedHTML)) {
        createMessage();
        console.log(newMessage)
      }
    }
  };
```

My Quill modules look like this:

```
const modules = {
   toolbar: [
   ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote'],
   [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }, { 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],
   ['link', 'image']
   ],
};
```

Adding the following breaks the editor (it disappears from frontend, with no console error)

```
const modules = {
   toolbar: [
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote'],
      [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }, { 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],
      ['link', 'image']
   ],
   keyboard:{
      bindings:{
         custom: {  //tried changing this to enter, still no luck
            key: 13,
            handler: function() {
               // do nothing
            }
          },
      }
  }
  };
```

My Quill component:

```
<ReactQuill
    theme="snow"
    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
    value={newMessage}
    onChange={setNewMessage}
    modules={modules}
    formats={formats}
    placeholder="What's on your mind?"/>

<button className="sendButton" onClick={createMessage}>
    <img src={sendIcon} alt="Send" />
</button>
```

I appreciate any help/suggestions!

I checked out several posts on Stackoverflow and Github issues on this and I couldn't unblock myself. Did I try Chat GPT too? yes  no luck.

I read Quill's [docs on Keyboards](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/#configuration), where they mention there are several keys that have default functions that can be overwritten, but I'm having a hard time using the method they suggest to overrwrite Enter's functionality.